# How to create a jquery function for li

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have created a div with a `<ul>` that holds the list of the filters and when any `<li>` us clicked it shows the corresponding filters.

https://jsfiddle.net/2x8enu54/

The following doesnt look very promising:

```
$(".f1").click(function(){
    $(".Field1").removeClass("hidden");
    $(".Field2").addClass("hidden");
    $(".Field3").addClass("hidden");
});
```

How can I create a function so that when a `li` from the 'selectul' div is clicked the respective results are displayed in the 'optionsdiv'.

Many thanks.

Comment: please explain your query.what you want to achieve?

Comment: @GSB When Field1 is clicked, the options for Field1 should be listed. When Field1 is clicked, the options for Field2 should be listed. Thats all. But the other option except the field selected should be hidden. But I dont want to make it like the code i pasted in the question. How can i achieve this with a function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would annotate each of your li elements like so :

```
<li class="clickable" data-field="1"><div class="itemslist">Field1</div></li>
<li class="clickable" data-field="2"><div class="itemslist">Field2</div></li>
<li class="clickable" data-field="3"><div class="itemslist">Field3</div></li>
<li class="clickable" data-field="4"><div class="itemslist">Field4</div></li>
<li class="clickable" data-field="5"><div class="itemslist">Field5</div></li>
```

and make your checkbox sections like so :

```
<div class="Field1 Field">
<h3>Options for Field1</h3>
<input type = "checkbox" value="1" />option1
<input type = "checkbox" value="2">option2
<input type = "checkbox" value="3">option3
</div>
</li>
<li><div class="Field2 Field">
<h3>Options for Field2</h3>
<input type = "checkbox" value="11">option11
<input type = "checkbox" value="12">option12
<input type = "checkbox" value="13">option13
</div>
</li>
<li>
<div class="Field3 Field">
<h3>Options for Field3</h3>
<input type = "checkbox" value="21">option21
<input type = "checkbox" value="22">option23
<input type = "checkbox" value="23">option23
</div>
```

and then make your script like so :

```
$(".clickable").click(function(){
    $(".Field").hide();
  var element=$(this).data("field");
  $(".Field" + element).show();
})

$(".Field").hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to do below changes with id and classes and script. I have also attached code snippet

```js
var curPage = "";
$(document).on("click", "#selectul  a", function() {

  if (curPage.length) {
    $("#" + curPage).hide();
  }
  curPage = $(this).data("page");
  
  $("#" + curPage).show();
  $(this).addClass('activeli').siblings().removeClass('active');


});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: helvetica;
  font-size: 20px;
}

#content {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: auto;
  width: 60%;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 12px;
}

ul,
ul#selectul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

#selectul li {
  border: 1px solid red;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#selectul li:hover {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}

#mainbox {
  padding: 20px;
}

#selectitems {
  float: left;
}

.itemslist {
  padding: 7px;
}

#optionsdiv {
  float: left;
  width: 350px;
  height: 193px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.activeli {
  background-color: red;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="content">
  <div id="mainbox">

    <div id="selectitems">
      <ul id="selectul">
        <li id="f1">
          <a data-page="page0">
            <div class="itemslist">Field1</div>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li id="f2">
          <a data-page="page1">
            <div class="itemslist">Field2</div>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li id="f3">
          <a data-page="page2">
            <div class="itemslist">Field3</div>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li id="f4">
          <a data-page="page3">
            <div class="itemslist">Field4</div>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li id="f5">
          <a data-page="page4">
            <div class="itemslist">Field5</div>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="optionsdiv">

      <ul>

        <li>

          <div id="page0" class="Field1 hidden">
            <h3>Options for Field1</h3>
            <input type="checkbox" value="1" />option1
            <input type="checkbox" value="2">option2
            <input type="checkbox" value="3">option3
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div id="page1" class="Field2 hidden">
            <h3>Options for Field2</h3>
            <input type="checkbox" value="11">option11
            <input type="checkbox" value="12">option12
            <input type="checkbox" value="13">option13
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div id="page2" class="Field3 hidden">
            <h3>Options for Field3</h3>
            <input type="checkbox" value="21">option21
            <input type="checkbox" value="22">option23
            <input type="checkbox" value="23">option23
          </div>
        </li>

<li>
          <div id="page3" class="Field4 hidden">
            <h3>Options for Field4</h3>
            <input type="checkbox" value="31">option31
            <input type="checkbox" value="32">option33
            <input type="checkbox" value="33">option33
          </div>
        </li>
      
<li>
          <div id="page4" class="Field5 hidden">
            <h3>Options for Field5</h3>
            <input type="checkbox" value="41">option41
            <input type="checkbox" value="42">option42
            <input type="checkbox" value="43">option43
          </div>
        </li>
</ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a ton. It helped !!